# Modify property inside of a behaviourRelay array in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have an array defined using RxSwift as

```
public var calendarNDays = BehaviorRelay<[CalendarControlDayModel]>(value: [])
```

CalendarControlDayModel is a structure as below.

```swift
struct CalendarControlDayModel {
        var date: String = ""
        var day: Int = 0
        var name: String = "" 
}
```

Once the `calendarNDays` is updated with elements at some point of time I want to modify the name property of i-th element in the array.

Like `self.calendarNDays.value[i].name = "Nancy"`. However, I get the compilation error "Cannot assign to property: 'value' is a get-only property".

What is the way to modify a particular property of an element in a behaviour relay array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the compiler suggests the `value` in `BehaviorRelay` is a read-only property.

Therefore in order to make changes to the array you first need to copy it and use the `accept` method to reflect the changes.

Similar to

```
var update = calendarNDays.value
update[i].name = “Nancy”
calendarNDays.accept(update)
```